# How to create db file with SQLiteStudio

Tags: sqlitestudio

I have created the database for my Android app using SQLiteStudio 3.0.5 and now I need to save/export the one as .db file, but i found only the export to .sql-file. So, what should I do to make such procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create database in SQLiteStudio it already is a proper sqlite database file. If you need to name it with `.db` extension, just rename the file in any file manager.

Comment: @Kitwradr I didn't write this answer

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to export the SQL command, and not the database itself.

Right-click on the database, and select "Export the database".